# How do I add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to the plist file via the config.xml?

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm working on a new app and trying to submit to itunes via the application loader for the first time. The ipa file is built by the phonegap build online service and the app uses the cordova camera plugin amongst others.

When I upload the ipa file with application loader it all appears to be successful but a few minutes later I receive an email with the following:

> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

And a similar paragraph relating to NSCameraUsageDescription

I have tried numerous fixes found online including adding any & all of the following to the config.xml:

```
 <platform name="ios">
.....
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
<string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>

</platform>
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>For taking pictures</string>
</gap:config-file>
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>For uploading images</string>
</gap:config-file>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" >  
    <variable name="NSCameraUsageDescription" value="Take pictures of stuff" />
    <variable name="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" value="App would like to access the library." />
</plugin>
```

Which are taken from the official plugin documentation as well as several other questions on stackoverflow, but every single submission returns the same email. I can't seem to figure out what the correct line is to add to the config.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The phonegap build service uses cli-6.5.0 by default which means you need to add the following to the config.xml inside the widget tags but not inside the platform tags..

```
<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" mode="replace">
<string>App would like to access the camera.</string>
</config-file>

<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" mode="replace">
  <string>App would like to access the camera.</string>
</config-file>
```

Taken from http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/

Answer (score 0):

You have to also mention your target inside the config-file element to make this working:

```
<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" mode="replace" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Paypal maybe access the camera</string>
</config-file>

<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" mode="replace" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Paypal maybe access the photo library</string>
</config-file>
```